# given $x,y$ and $\theta$, calculate its distance to origin $(0,0,0)$

Tags: fixed-points

Apologies if this question sounds really dumb, but I am faced with a set of points:

$x_1,y_1,\theta_1$

$x_2,y_2,\theta_2$
..

and I am looking to work out the distance between each row $(x_1,y_1,\theta_1)$ to the origin $(0,0,0)$. I have not encountered this before and I was wondering what the formula for compute this would be. A google search does not seem to reveal a lot :(

Comment: What is $\theta$ here?

Comment: Are these coordinates spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Bernard thank you for this. This image shows what theta is: https://pasteboard.co/JpP7Slh.png I dont know if theta helps to find the distance (assuming some form of speherical coordinate). Hence my question!

Comment: @Clayton Yes! please see the image I have attached above.

Comment: But your image is in the $(x,y)$ plane. It has nothing to do with a 3d space.

Comment: @Bernard yes you are right, this is what is confusing me :( from the image, it just looks like a 2D field :(

Comment: Would per chance, in a better drawn figure, θ be the inclination angle w.r.t. the $z$-axis?

Answer (score 0):

Using Pythagoras' theorem I would say that for the first set it is equal to
$$\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}$$
if I have understood you correctly?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, but they are speherical coordinates, not caterisian.

Comment: @AJW I didn't realsie, you should say so in the question probably, unless the angle specified makes it clear (I've never done spherical trig before, i don't know).

Comment: I have updated the question, apologies for the confusion.